# Updating an object stored in one Activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating an object called "AppEngine" inside my first activity. This AppEngine object stores and arrayList of Events, and begins with 2 events inside it.

From the first Activity I click a button which takes me to a second Activity in which I add an event object to the arrayList by using.

```
appEngine.getList.add(new Event)
```

When inside Activity 2, If I am to call `appEngine.getList.size()` the size is correctly returned as 3 and I can see the extra event.

When I switch back to Activity 2, I am calling `appEngine.getList.size()`however it only returns 2, and the extra event is not in there. How can i get the appEngine object to update?

Comment: I am assuming you are passing the list using the api putParcelableArrayListExtra() of Intent?

Comment: The array itself is not being passed, the appEngine is being passed using bundle.putSerializable("appEngine",appEngine"). This puts the entire Engine in activity 2, and the getList method is called inside activity 2.

Comment: mistype one of them? 'When inside Activity 2' and 'When I switch back to Activity 2'

Comment: So the problem is when you call getSerializable in Activity2 it return the different instance of the AppEngine and when you return back to the Activity1, list inside the AppEngine size is still 2. One solution to Your problem is declare your AppEngine class as Singleton and Don't pass using putSerializable API instead get use the Singleton instance and update the list.

Answer (score 0):

save your array list in shared preference like this create a AppPreference Class:-

```
public class AppPreference {

private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
private static SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor;

public static Set<AppEngine> getList(Context ctx) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        return mPrefs.getStringSet("AppEngineList", null);
    }

    public static void setList(Context ctx, ArrayList<AppEngine> value) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.addAll(value);
        mPrefsEditor.putStringSet("AppEngineList", set);
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
   }
}
```

set your value from first activity like this:-

```
setList(YourActivity.class, list);
```

and get your list from anywhere in you app:-

```
ArrayLis<AppEngine> list = AppPreference.getList(yourActivity.class);
```

Comment: Which activity do I create the AppPreference class and how do I access it from the second activity?

Comment: you have to create a java class in your package. actually you can use shared preference like mini database in your aap this is the best practice to save values in your app and get these values from where you want

Comment: this will actually store the data to local storage on the phone, which might be overkill? meaning the state of the data will actually persist when you completely close the app, and not jsut when switching between activitys

Comment: adjust the code according to your situation and it will sure you will like this code

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the appEnginge object to persist during a single app session and not persist trough a complete app close/restart, then you should use a handler class.

EngineHandler.java:

```
public static class engineHandler {
   public static appEnginge _appEngine;
}
```

and then just call

```
engineHandler._appEngine = _myAppengine;
engineHandler._appEngine.getList().add(new Event);
```

from your activity(s). The engineHandler will be accessible from any activity in your application.

Comment: I am atempting to do implement this code but am getting an error saying static is not allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to think each Activity is totally separated execution. Technically it's arguable, but it is good assumption to design cleaner and safer software.

Given assumption, there are several approaches to maintain data across Activities in an app.

- As @Sandeep Malik's answer, use SharedPreference OS-given storage.
- Similar to @Joachim Haglund's answer, use Singleton pattern to maintain an object in app.
- Or, use small database like [Realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-database).

Every approach has similar fashion; there should be an isolated and independent storage which is not belonged to one of Activity but belonged to [ApplicationContext](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) or underlying framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Singleton** design Pattern.

You create one object from **AppEnginRepository** with eventList field and in your app you just **get** it and each time you want, you **change** it.

```
public class AppEnginRepository {

    private List<Event> eventList;

    private static final AppEnginRepository ourInstance = new AppEnginRepository();

    public static AppEnginRepository getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private AppEnginRepository() {
        eventList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Event> getEventList() {
        return eventList;
    }

    public void setEventList(List<Event> eventList) {
        this.eventList = eventList;
    }


}
```

In your Activities

```
AppEnginRepository enginRepository=AppEnginRepository.getInstance();
List<Event> eventList=enginRepository.getEventList();
eventList.add(new Event());
int eventListSize=eventList.size();
```